# Typescript and React: Failing type inference when using React.Component and conditional typed props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

In below setup, I try to get the correct, inferred type for the value parameter in the onChange function. Below setup gives me a value with type `string | number` though I would have thought it should be `string` given that value is assigned a `string`.

```
import * as React from 'react'

type NumberProps = {
    decimals: number;
};

type StringProps = {};

type Props<T> = {
    value: T;
    onChange: (value: T) => void;
} & (T extends number ? NumberProps : StringProps);

class Y<T extends string | number> extends React.Component<Props<T>> {}

new Y({ value: 2.5, onChange:((value) => { /* value is inferred as string | number, but should be number */ })})
```

Two things will make the inference correct - but will of course be incorrect in other ways - but might give a clue to what's wrong:

1. I can remove this part of the Props type: `& (T extends number ?
   NumberProps : StringProps);`
2. I can make `Y`derive from something other than React.Component, for
   example a class like `class X<T> { constructor(props: T) {} }`.

Am I doing/expecting something wrong, or is this a bug in Typescript and/or React types.

Comment: What's the value of `number` in `T extends number ...`? Where was it defined?

Comment: @JohnKennedy that's the built-in type `number` it refers to.

Comment: In that case I don't think what you want to do will work. You can't check that `number` which is a built-in type is defined. You need to remove that and have the type you want there.

Comment: @JohnKennedy I'm not sure I follow you? This works if I don't derive from React.Component but use a class like `class X<T> { constructor(props: T) {} }`

Answer (score 0):

If the type inference is not working out, you can explicitly specify the value of the type parameter yourself:

```
new Y<string>({ value: 'test', onChange:((value) => { /* value is now a string */ })})
```

Comment: Correct, but that does not answer my question :)